# Kernel 4.9 module mismatch

Tags: debian, kernel, drivers, qemu, debootstrap

I installed Debian Jessie with debootstrap, updated the kernel to `4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64` and created an image of it. Now, I wanted to start Jessie with qemu and the following command: `qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel bzImage -append "root=/dev/sda" -hda jessie.img -net nic -enable-kvm -nographic -m 2G`. To obtain the bzImage, I downloaded and compiled Kernel [version 4.9 from Linus' github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/releases/tag/v4.9).

The problem I am facing now, is a version mismatch, although I have (at least I thought so) the proper versions:

```
[   49.506967] pcwd_usb: version magic '4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '4.9.0 SMP mod_unload '
```

Does anybody know, which kernel version I have to get (and where)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your kernel modules (installed inside the VM) to match your kernel image. Inside the VM, you installed the Debian kernel, which you can grab either from `/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64` inside the VM or from https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64 (at least, if that's where you downloaded the newer kernel from to update the VM). Surprised it worked at all without the initrd, too.

PS: It's probably easier to just boot using the bootloader (grub) installed in the image.

Comment: That fixed the problem, thank you. I was able to boot the vm!